# Use of "which" in the middle of the sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-order, questions

Consider this sentence:

> There are many questions in this question
>
> 1. I don't know to answer which one
> 2. I don't know which one to answer
> 3. I don't know which to answer
> 4. I don't know which one I should answer

I guess 2 and 4 are the ones that I heard most. However, I'm not sure what makes the first one different from the rest and illegible.

Comment: 2, 3, and 4 are all fine, but I can't give you a more complete answer without more information about why this is difficult or confusing for you.

Comment: @Andrew more details was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three sentences:

2. I don't know which one to answer.
3. I don't know which to answer.
4. I don't know which one I should answer.

are correct.

The first two are infinitival clauses. Other similar examples, formed by a wh-word and an infinitive, are:

5. I don't know what to do.
6. I don't know how to answer this question.
7. I don't know where to go.
8. I don't know who to ask.
9. I don't know when to stop.

Just as 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 are reduced forms of the sentences containing the embedded questions below:

5'. I don't know what I should do.

6'. I don't know how I should answer this question.

7'. I don't know where I should go.

8'. I don't know who I should ask.

9'. I don't know when I should stop.

2 and 3 are abridged forms of 4.